# What can be done to restore a Down Sleeping Bag after compressed storage?

Tags: sleeping-bags, maintenance, down

I, unfortunately, am in the situation where my down sleeping bag has been stored in a compressed state for approximately 11 months (it was bought and used once before this).

I have read in many places that down bags should never be stored while compressed. However, is there anything at all I can do to restore/improve the situation now?

Comment: Oh man. I'm sorry to hear that. I get twitchy if my bag is compressed for more than a couple days. I can think of a few people who'd like to see where this goes.

Comment: I'll toss in an answer on the other question, but I don't think you have too much to worry about here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried tossing it in a dryer on Air Fluff with some tennis balls, for a little while?

Edit: See also suggestions [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/how-can-i-inflate-or-plump-up-my-my-sleeping-bag?rq=1).